# Find annotation in Spring proxy bean

Tags: spring

I have created my own annotation for classes: `@MyAnnotation`, and have annotated two classes with it.

I have also annotated a few methods in these classes with Spring's `@Transactional`. According to the [Spring documentation for Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained), the bean factory actually wraps my class into a proxy.

Last, I use the following code to retrieve the annotated beans.

1. Method `getBeansWithAnnotation` correctly returns my declared beans. *Good.*
2. The class of the bean is actually a proxy class generated by Spring. *Good*, this means the `@Transactional` attribute is found and works.
3. Method findAnnotation does not find `MyAnnotation` in the bean. *Bad*. I wish I could read this annotation from the actual classes or proxies seamlessly.

If a bean is a proxy, how can I find the annotations on the actual class ?

What should I be using instead of `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation()` for the desired result ?

```
Map<String,Object> beans = ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
System.out.println(beans.size());
// prints 2. ok !

for (Object bean: services.values()) {
  System.out.println(bean.getClass());
  // $Proxy

  MyAnnotation annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(svc.getClass(), MyAnnotation.class);
  //
  // Problem ! annotation is null !
  //
}
```

Comment: What kind of a proxy is it?  (JDK versus cglib, etc).

Comment: I guess Spring uses JDK proxies by default.

Comment: Seems like this would be a good enhancement to the framework. Have you looked into this since you posted quite some time ago?

Answer (score 15):

You can find the real class of the proxied bean by calling [AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils.html#ultimateTargetClass%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Determine
>   the ultimate target class of the given bean instance, traversing not
>   only a top-level proxy but any number of nested proxies as well - as
>   long as possible without side effects, that is, just for singleton
>   targets.

Answer (score 11):

The solution is not to work on the bean itself, but to ask the application context instead.

Use method [ApplicationContext#findAnnotationOnBean(String,Class)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#findAnnotationOnBean%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29).

```
Map<String,Object> beans = ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
System.out.println(beans.size());
// prints 2. ok !

for (Object bean: services.values()) {
  System.out.println(bean.getClass());
  // $Proxy

  /* MyAnnotation annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(svc.getClass(), MyAnnotation.class);
  // Problem ! annotation is null !
   */

  MyAnnotation annotation = ctx.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName, MyAnnotation.class);
  // Yay ! Correct !
}
```

Comment: How do you find *methods* that have the given annotation?

Comment: This seems to (non-deterministically) only work part of the time, even though I'm running the same bundled application JAR multiple times on the same platform and JRE