# Spring Profile Based Jersey Rest Service publish

Tags: java, spring, jersey

It is possible to publish jersey rest service based on spring profile?
lets say as following example, how can I publish `RegisterServices1` when using `profile1`?

```
public class ApiGWRestApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

   public ApiGWRestApplicationConfig() {     
      register(RegisterServicesApiGWInterface.class);
    }
}

@Service
@Profile("profile1")
@Path(SystemConstants.REST_REGISTER)
public class RegisterServices1 implements RegisterServicesApiGWInterface {
```

}

```
@Service
@Profile("profile2")
@Path(SystemConstants.REST_REGISTER)
public class RegisterServices2 implements RegisterServicesApiGWInterface{}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet-kagw</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ttech.tims.imos.web.ApiGWRestApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Maybe you can inject the ApplicationContext into the ResourceConfig, and [get all the beans that are annotated with @Path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14236424/2587435). You can register them the same way with `register`. Just an idea. I never tried it

Comment: actually, it does not work, because ResourceConfig  is initialized in web.xml where out of the spring context initialization process

Comment: Try it out with [this project](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-example/tree/master/src/main/java/com/underdog/jersey/spring/example). There's no web.xml. It's all programmatic, even spring configuration with SpringInitializer. The ResourceConfig is automatically picked up from the @ApplicationPath annotation. I will give it a shot later if it doesn't work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you can do is get a hold of the `ApplicationContext` and use [`getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation-java.lang.Class-). This will give you all the resource instances that are part of the profile. Then you can register the instances.

I though it would be possible to inject the `ApplicationContext` into the `ResourceConfig`, but as mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198688/spring-profile-based-jersey-rest-service-publish#comment73469658_43198688) above, it seems the creation of the `ResourceConfig` doesn't have access to it yet.

What I was able to get to work, is to use a JAX-RS `Feature` which also has access to registration methods, just like you have in the `ResourceConfig`. Using the `Feature` will give you access to the `ApplicationContext`

```
public class SpringProfilesFeature implements Feature {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext featureContext) {
        Map<String, Object> resources = context.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class);

        resources.values().forEach(resource -> featureContext.register(resource));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then just register the feature with the `ResourceConfig`

```
public AppConfig() {
    register(SpringProfilesFeature.class);
}
```

Remove any other registrations you have for all your resources. Just let the feature register them.

I've confirmed that this works. Not sure how you set your profile for the environment, but hopefully this is something you already know how to do.