# Supply lambda context to Jersey resource

Tags: java, dependency-injection, aws-lambda, jersey

I'm using [aws-serverless-java-container](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container) to wrap a Jersey service in a AWS Lambda. I decided to use function alias to have a "test" and "prod" stage that eventually points to different versions of the lambda function.

I need to select some properties in a .properties file based on that alias, basically because I need to talk to a "test" or "prod" DB or use a different endpoint to invoke an external web service.

For such purpose I need to invoke the method getInvokedFunctionArn of the [Context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-context-object.html). Unfortunately the Jersey resource is not aware of such context by default.

Below a sample resource:

```
@Path("/pet")
public class PetResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    public Response createPet() {
        // how to call getInvokedFunctionArn from Lambda context object?
        return Response.status(200).entity("{'result': 'success'}").build();
    }
}
```

How can I enable the Jersey resource to have the invoked ARN? Can I inject it?

The lambda handler is defined as:

```
public class PetLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    private static final ResourceConfig jerseyApplication = new ResourceConfig().register(PetResource.class)
            .register(JacksonFeature.class);

    private static final JerseyLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler = JerseyLambdaContainerHandler
            .getAwsProxyHandler(jerseyApplication);

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer helped? if not framework you use/consider for dependency-injection? did you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0

Comment: No, it didn't help. I'm not looking for another DI framework like spring and your solution doesn't outline a way to choose one of the two profiles based on the lambda's execution context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inject the Lambda context automatically. However, you can retrieve it form the `ContainerRequestContext` object. The [`serverless-java-container`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container) framework adds it as [a request property](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/blob/master/aws-serverless-java-container-jersey/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/serverless/proxy/jersey/JerseyHandlerFilter.java#L145).

You can probably do something like this (have not tested the code):

```java
@GET
public String testLambdaContext(@Context ContainerRequestContext containerRequest) {
   Context lambdaContext =
       (Context) containerRequest.getProperty(RequestReader.LAMBDA_CONTEXT_PROPERTY);
   return lambdaContext.getInvokedFunctionArn()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Inject context to jersey resources using [Spring profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198688/spring-profile-based-jersey-rest-service-publish/43199936#43199936)

Define for test and prod profiles different methods/objects

If you don't have Spring, you can check [jersey integration](https://medium.com/@shask9/developing-restful-web-services-using-jax-rs-jersey-and-spring-b4e1eb8e2467)

> jersey-spring4 module that will act as the integration bridge for Spring and Jersey.

See full example in github [aws-serverless-java-container](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring) library running a Spring application with profiles in AWS Lambda

> There are two ways to activate Spring Profiles (as defined with the @Profile annotation). We recommend using the static initializer that receives a list of profiles. The Serverless Java Container framework takes care of setting the profile and initializing the application at once.
>
> ```
> public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
>     private static SpringLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
>     static {
>         try {
>             AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
>             applicationContext.register(PetStoreSpringAppConfig.class);
>             handler = SpringLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(applicationContext, "profile-1", "profile-2");
> ```

Comment: I would prefer to not use another DI framework like Spring, since Jersey already use HK2. Moreover your proposed solution doesn't allow to choose "profile-1" or "profile-2" based on the lambda's execution context.