# Java Spring - enforce no bean inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

First, some code:

```java
interface Foo {
  void bar();
}

@Configuration
class FooConfig {
  @Bean
  public Foo foo() { return new MagicFoo(); }
  class MagicFoo implements Foo { ... }
}

@Component
class FooImpl implements Foo {
  public void bar() { }
}

@Component
class BarImpl {
  final Foo foo;
  public BarImpl(Foo foo) { this.foo = foo; }
}
```

As this example stands, when `BarImpl` is instantiated, the Spring framework will look for a bean matching `Foo` and prefer the bean defined by `FooConfig` (i.e. the `MagicFoo`) over the implementing-class `FooImpl`.

My question is: is there any way to configure this code so that ONLY beans directly matching the interface (e.g. `Foo`), and not any implementing classes (e.g. `FooImpl`) are acceptable for a particular interface dependency? I.e. somehow configure Spring to treat `Foo` dependencies in this special way.

In such a configuration, if I removed `FooConfig`, I would get an error trying to instantiate `BarImpl` because no suitable bean can be found, even though a bean for `FooImpl` is available. In other words, with this desired configuration in place, the developer is forced to explicitly define beans for the identified interface instead of labeling implementing classes as beans.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple beans implementing `Foo`, they are all candidates for autowiring a parameter of type `Foo`.

You cannot distinguish between beans created by `@Bean` vs beans created by `@Component`.

You can however use `@Qualifier` to isolate/separate them.

```java
@Configuration
class FooConfig {
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("ABC")
  public Foo foo() { return new MagicFoo(); }
  class MagicFoo implements Foo { ... }
}

@Component
@Qualifier("XYZ")
class FooImpl implements Foo {
  public void bar() { }
}

@Component
class BarImpl {
  final Foo foo;
  public BarImpl(@Qualifier("ABC") Foo foo) { this.foo = foo; }
}
```

The parameter can now only be autowired by the `@Bean` created bean, because that is the only one with the correct qualifier.

Comment: What if I put a qualifier on `FooImpl` but not on `Foo` and have no `@Qualifier` on the `BarImpl` parameter - will `FooImpl` be considered as a candidate? I.e. if I use `@Qualifier` on a bean, can the bean only get used in places that opt-in to that `@Qualifer`, or are all qualified beans, by default, allowed?

Comment: @GordonBean I believe that an autowire without a qualifier will look for *all* beans of that type.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I've accomplished the desired behavior with the following setup:

- I created an annotation for the implementations that should not be used as beans for the special interfaces. (e.g. `@ActvityImplementation`)

  - The special interfaces also have an associated annotation that identifies them. (e.g. `@ActivityInterface`)
- I have a configuration class that pulls in all the beans annotated with the `@ActivityImplementation` annotation.

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48633041/2288986
- The configuration class reflects on each implementation bean to extract the interface with the `@ActivityInterface` annotation.
- For each implementation bean, I query the Spring application context for a bean matching the interface and check the type of the returned bean.

  - If the returned bean matches the implementation type (as opposed to the intended "magic" type) I throw an error.

This logic ensures that I (and anyone else using the framework) cannot forget to configure the "magic" interface implementation. When the "magic" implementation is present, it is the bean returned for the interface. When the "magic" implementation is not present, Spring falls back to the implementation bean, which then triggers the error.