# when will the class get proxied by SpringCGLB

Tags: java, spring

I can sometimes get the annotation via `[object].getClass().isAnnotationPresent([Annotation.class])`
but sometimes not.
So I turn on the debug mode and find the difference:
In the fist picture, b.getClass() return the actual class: `stan.beans.HisBean`
[image]
But in the second picture, it actually return something different, looks like a modified class by Spring framework so I use the proxied word in the title:
class packagepath.Handler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da96cafa

[image]

Thanks to @Teppic I figure out we can use `AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass()` to get the non-proxied class

**But my question now is :**

When will SpringCGLB proxy the class? Is there any configuration I can change? Cause I think both my screenshots use the same configuration. They almost shadow each other.

**Important Info Thanks to @M. Deinum**
The second bean class(proxied one) has Spring Cache `@Cacheable` annotation on some methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find annotation in Spring proxy bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257092/find-annotation-in-spring-proxy-bean)

Comment: Ah Yes I will close it

Comment: @teppic Actually I updated the question now

Comment: Without seeing the bean sources and configuration this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually good point! The only difference between the first and second screenshot is that second one( proxied bean ) has  the Spring Cache annotation `@Cacheable`. Actually I think that is possibly the reason. Non-looker does have a clear mind!!!

Comment: My guess: CGLIG proxies in AOP as well as in Spring Cache framework

Comment: Again without the code it is impossible to answer. Caching is implemented with AOP.

Comment: It is private code which can not be shown here. But I can tell the biggest difference is the Cache annotation @M. Denium